# How exactly do I answer my own question?

Tags: support

I put a [question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45477/does-tablet-size-affect-which-orientation-users-use) up on UX stack exchange but didn't get any truly satisfying answers so I went and did a survey myself, collated my data and created an infographic to allow for visual representation. I then went back to my post intending to share my results by answering my own question and clicked the Answer My Question button. Nothing happened. I've tried again several times since then on different days but I still can't answer my own question.

Do I need a certain standing before I can do this? Or is it a problem with my browser? Or have I got completely the wrong idea? A little research gave conflicting opinions, one person made it seem as if you changed your question so it contained the answers then clicked the button and the site would create a post for you, another stated you just answer it as you would any other question on the site.

I am using a Windows PC running XP SP3 and browsing using the latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked my pop up blocker and it turned out that was blocking the pop up that checks if you really want to answer your own question. Once turned off it allows me to answer my own question with no problems.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I think other people have had this issue in the past too, so we can refer people to this post if it happens to them.

Comment: How meta indeed.

Comment: It's almost ironic that asking this question got me the Self Learner badge!